# How to add Score to a game

Tags: java

I am trying to add a score feature to my game. I know that where I have a remove function I now need to add code which means that whenever an enemy is removed it contributes to the score of the game but I don't know how to implement that into my game using code. Below I have included relevant code.

```
      boolean alive() {
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
          Bullet bullet = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
          if (bullet.x > x && bullet.x < x + pixelsize * 7 && bullet.y > y && bullet.y < y + 5 * pixelsize) {
            bullets.remove(i);
            bullet.alive = false;
            return false;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
          Bullet bullet = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
          if (bullet.alive == false) {
            bullets.remove(i);
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create an `int score` variable at the sketch level.

```
int score = 0;
```

**Step 2:** Increment that variable whenever you want to increase the score.

```
score += 100;
```

**Step 3:** Display that score in the `draw()` function whenever and wherever you want the score to be displayed.

```
text("Score: " + score, 20, 20);
```

Also, I noticed that you're comparing `String` values with the `==` operator. **Don't do that.** Instead, use the `equals()` function:

```
String x = "test";
if(x.equals("blah")){
   //whatever
}
```

Comment: @mo.h When do you want the score to increase? When does that happen in your code? That's where you need to increment the variable.

Comment: So I want it to increase every time an enemy is removed from the game because of a collision with a bullet:

the original line of code is this:   bullets.remove(i);

an I want it so that every time their is a colission their is an added score so i changed that line of code to bullets.remove(i) & score +=100; which i know is incorrect

Comment: Why would you add an `&`? Where are you getting that syntax? Just do it in two lines of code.

Comment: @mo.h You'd put it wherever you want the score to increment. When do you want that to happen? Maybe when an enemy is killed?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you'd like the score to be permanent or not. If so,  you could write the scores to a simple csv file to get a leaderbord. Eaven a normal texfile would do.